# Is $scope a real service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is $scope a service or an instance of $rootScope in AngularJS ？

```
var $injector = angular.element(document).injector();
$injector.get('$rootScope'); //it will return $rootScope  
$injector.get('$scope');  //it will return undefined
```

So I doubt the $scope is not a 'real' service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$scope` is neither a service nor an instance of `$rootScope`. It is an instance of `Scope` (which is a private constructor in Angular's code). In fact, the `$rootScope` service's provider returns an instance of `Scope`.

Let's start from the beginning:

1. Angular has a private (as in not directly accessible from outside, e.g. by you) constructor, called `Scope`.
2. `Scope` can be used by Angular to create new scope objects. (Indeed, all scopes, including isolate scopes and the rootScope itself, are internally created using `new Scope()`.)
3. Every scope object has a `$new()` method, which creates a new scope object that prototypically inherits from the scope whose `$new()` method was called.
4. As soon as Angular is loaded, it "requires" the `$rootScope` service, which creates the rootScope: a plain old Scope object (without a parent scope). Since services are singletons in Angular, anytime the `$rootScope` service is injected, that same rootScope object is provided.
5. Whenever a new scope is required (e.g. for a directive that defines a new scope (either normal or isolate), for a controller etc.), a new Scope object is created and returned using the aforementioned `$new()` method of an already existing Scope object (i.e. the rootScope or a descendant of the rootScope).
6. So, what is the `$scope` dependency injected into the controllers ?
   It is a Scope object, created by Angular's calling the enclosing scope's `$new()` method and passed to the controller constructor. (So, it is not a service, but a Scope instance created for us by Angular.)

---

That said, your code could be changed like this:

```
var $injector = angular.element(document).injector();
$injector.get('$rootScope');         // it will return $rootScope  
$injector.get('$rootScope').$new();  // it will return a new scope
                                     // (prototypically inheriting from $rootScope)
// Or, if you have access to some other scope
// (example to the controller's $scope)
$scope.$new();  // it will return a new scope
                // (prototypically inheriting from $scope)
```

Comment: Very nice and detailed explanation, thanks for that. I got a question related to your answer. 
Is injecting $scope as in
`$injector.get('$rootScope').$new()`
same as `['$scope', function($scope){}]` ? I mean, are they the same scope? If not, how can I use $injector to achieve the second one?

Comment: @code90, conceptually, thay are the same kind if thing. `['$scope', function($scope){}]` does a little more under the hood (depending on the exact context). What are you trying to achieve (and why can't you use the injected instance) ?

Comment: It is just out of curiosity. I recently developed a habit of using $injector and tried it on $scope with no success.  that's why I asked it.

Comment: @code90, I suggest you get out of that habit :) You shouldn't use unless there is a real reason.

Comment: On some occasions, I do have some good reasons to use it, such as checking whether a module or a service is available. But also, using it to me seems like more clean code and more control over the flow. Any real reason why not suggest using it? Any bottleneck performance wise ?

Comment: Performancewise, it shouldn't make a difference. But you it make your code less readable and is more difficult to test things.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one true scope in Angular and that is $rootScope.  Every other scope inherits from it.  $scope is Angular's mechanism to create a model in an mvvm world.

Comment: Em...actually it does not !

Comment: It makes perfect sense -- go read the doc -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Oh, "read the docs" !? Why didn't I think of that ? Give me a min... ... ...OK, I read it...and it still doesn't make sense. All scopes are "true scopes". Some just happen to be childs of others. And _"$scope is Angular's mechanism to create a model"_ isn't really informative either. Besides, Angular is rather "model-agnostic" so you have great flexibility creating your models.

Comment: Can't do anything to help your comprehension

Answer (score 0):

$scope inherit from $rootScope (prototype) but they are define always in context of the views. Number of directives create a new scope (ng-include, ng-if and others), infact `ng-controller` too creates a new scope that is then linked to the view. The important thing here is that scope does not have a independent existence, and are always referenced in connection of views.

Comment: _"but they are define always in context of the views"_ No, they are not. They are defined wherever you (or Angular) define them. You can create as many new scopes ss you wish and place them anywhere (it just does not make sense:)).

Comment: Yes i forgot you can create new scope with `$scope.$new`. My bad. But yes it does not make sense to create scope unless they serve some purpose defined by the view.